# Creating larger NiFi flow files when using the ConsumeKafka processor

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I've created a simple NiFi pipeline that reads a stream of data from a Kafka topic (using `ConsumeKafka`) and writes it to the HDFS (using `PutHDFS`). Currently, I'm seeing lots of small files being created on the HDFS. A new file is created about once a second, some with only one or two records.

I want fewer, larger files to be written to the HDFS.

I have the following settings in `ConsumeKafka`:

```
Message Demarcator = <new line>
Max Poll Records = 10000
Max Uncommitted Time = 20s
```

In the past I've used Flume instead of Nifi, and it has `batchSize` and `batchDurationMillis`, which allow me to tweak how big HDFS files are. It seems like `ConsumeKafka` in Nifi is missing a `batchDurationMillis` equivalent.

What's the solution in NiFi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Message Demarcator and Max Poll Records is the correct approach to get multiple messages per flow file. You may want to slow down the ConsumeKafka processor by adjusting the Run Schedule (on the scheduling tab) from 0 sec which means run as fast as possible, to something like 1 second or whatever makes sense for you to grab more data.

Even with the above, you would likely still want to stick a MergeContent processor before PutHDFS, and merge together flow files based on size so that you can wait til you have the appropriate amount of data before writing to HDFS.

How to use MergeContent will depend on the type of data you are merging... If you have Avro, there is a specific merge strategy for Avro. If you have JSON you can merge them one after another, or you can wrap them with a header, footer, and demarcator to make a valid JSON array.

Comment: Thanks, the Run Schedule is what I needed to change.

Comment: @Bryan Bende If I were to batch 10 records into 1 Flow File and deposit into Kafka, how many records does ConsumeKafka returns in a single poll since "Max Poll Records" is specified as 10,000.  Does it return 10,000 * 10 records since every Kafka message (1 flow file has 10 records)?

Comment: When NiFi publishes to Kafka it is going to read the records from the flow file and one by one, and each record will be a message in Kafka, so that will publish 10 messages in your example. The consuming side the 10k is a max based on what is available at the time and what can be consumed in the poll time.